# tcolorbox inserting indent after code box

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted

*(the commented lines will be used later but as we can see in MWE, they aren't related with the problem)*

Why is there a par indent after the code box?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,breakable,xparse,skins}

\DeclareTCBListing{myminted}{O{}m!O{}}{%
  listing only,
  minted language=#2,
  minted options={%
    #1},
  #3}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{myminted}{R}
p1 = graph_plot(g)
p2 = f_omega_cycle(g)
p1 + p2
\end{myminted}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Manual says that `autoparskip` is the package default, in which case the `after` code is set to `after={\par}`, does either `after={}` or `nobeforeafter` help?

Comment: @ScottH., no. Both pull back the text so it appears on the right of the box, out of margin.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad.

Comment: I got these error `Package minted Error: You must have "pygmentize" installed to use this package`

Comment: @AndréC, yes. You need to install it: `pip install Pygments` It is a Python module.

Comment: what is `pip` (i'm on windows with MikTeX) ?

Comment: @AndréC, `pip` is a kind of fast way to install modules for Python. It is not related with TeX. But `minted` uses Python to color the code (rougly speaking).

Comment: So I have to install Python?

Comment: @AndréC, well, I don't use Windows, but Linux (which comes with Python).

Comment: @AndréC if you wanted to use `minted`, yes, you'd have to.

Answer (score 6):

By default, if you don't change `/tcb/before` nor `/tcb/after`, `tcolorbox` uses the `/tcb/autoparskip` style, which does the following:

- If the length of `\parskip` is greater than `0pt` at the beginning of the document, the `/tcb/parskip` style is executed.
- Otherwise, `/tcb/noparskip` is executed.

(see *Embedding into the Surroundings* in the `tcolorbox` manual). In your case, we can check with `\showthe\parskip` after `\begin{document}`, which prints the following lines on the terminal:

```latex
> 0.0pt plus 1.0pt.
l.44 \begin{document}\showthe\parskip
```

When used in a comparison of 〈dimen〉s, this won't be greater than `0pt` (the stretch component is thrown away). You can verify this with `\ifdim\parskip>0pt Y\else N\fi`, which will leave an `N` in the input stream. So, given your settings, since your box specifies neither `/tcb/before` nor `/tcb/after`, the `/tcb/noparskip` style will be executed. The `tcolorbox` manual tells us that this style is similar to:

```latex
\tcbset{
  noparskip/.style={
    before={\par\pagebreak[0]\smallskip\parindent=0pt},
    after={\par\smallskip}
  }
}
```

therefore `tcolorbox` automatically adds `\par\smallskip` after the box. As soon as the `\lipsum*` following your environment outputs a box, this starts a new paragraph, and since `\noindent` hasn't been used, you get normal paragraph indentation.

In case you don't want this indentation, you can use `after={\par\smallskip\noindent}` or `after={\par\noindent}` (depending on the desired vertical spacing) in your box options.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,xparse}

\DeclareTCBListing{myminted}{O{}m!O{}}{%
  after={\par\smallskip\noindent},
  listing only,
  minted language=#2,
  minted options={#1},
  #3}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{myminted}{R}
p1 = graph_plot(g)
p2 = f_omega_cycle(g)
p1 + p2
\end{myminted}
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation. I'll read it carefully. Also, I edited the post to delete comments. My fault.

Comment: No problem, next time will be perfect. :-)

Comment: How to make sure that the space between boxes and texts are well inserted? See the output [here](https://imgur.com/a/7XnVaYP) (with and without `\smallskip`)

Comment: `\smallskip` is... small. Did you try with `\bigskip`? Seems to work well here. (The skip can be discarded at page breaks, by design. You can use `\nobreak` before `\smallskip` if you really want white space after a box that is located *at the end of a page*, but this is *most probably not what you want.)*

Comment: Well, it would be good to have the correct spacing, like in displayed blocks, stretchable when necessary. I'm not sure, but sounds that a new par there is not what LaTeX would do around an equation, for example. Maybe `belowdisplayskip`. Lets see.

Comment: If we change `\setlength{\parskip}{2em}` (just an example value), the space above/below the box changes (but I'd like to keep it, since the box is **in the middle** of a paragraph.

Comment: `\smallskip`, `\medskip` and `\bigskip` are all stretchable and shrinkable by default (cf. `\smallskipamount` & Co.). Display formulas are handled very specially by TeX (no new paragraph), but the family of skips you mentioned is indeed involved. Regarding your latest comment: then don't set a positive `\parskip`. You can put the skip you want instead of `\smallskip` (e.g., `\vskip 6.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt\relax`), and you can remove it altogether!

Answer (score 4):

The following uses the LaTeX2e internal `\@endpetrue`, that is used to let `\end{<env>}` use a `\@doendpe` if the environment specifies it (such as `itemize` for example), to suppress the paragraph indent if there is no empty line after your `myminted`, but there will be an indent if you leave a blank line.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,breakable,xparse,skins}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\mynoindent
  {%
    \par
    \@endpetrue
  }
\makeatother

%\definecolor{bg}{gray}{0.95}
\DeclareTCBListing{myminted}{O{}m!O{}}{%
%  breakable=true,
%  listing engine=minted,
  listing only,
  minted language=#2,
%  minted style=default,
  minted options={%
%    linenos,
%    gobble=0,
%    breaklines=true,
%    breakafter=,,
%    fontsize=\small,
%    numbersep=8pt,
    #1},
%  boxsep=0pt,
%  left skip=0pt,
%  right skip=0pt,
%  left=25pt,
%  right=0pt,
%  top=3pt,
%  bottom=3pt,
%  arc=5pt,
%  leftrule=0pt,
%  rightrule=0pt,
%  bottomrule=2pt,
%  toprule=2pt,
%  colback=bg,
%  colframe=orange!70,
%  enhanced,
%  overlay={%
%    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
%    \fill[orange!20!white] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=20pt]frame.north west);
%    \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    after={\mynoindent},
  #3}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{myminted}{R}
p1 = graph_plot(g)
p2 = f_omega_cycle(g)
p1 + p2
\end{myminted}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{myminted}{R}
p1 = graph_plot(g)
p2 = f_omega_cycle(g)
p1 + p2
\end{myminted}

\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Is there an analogous of `\@doendpe` for `\begin{<env>}`?

Comment: @Sigur you mean to suppress the indentation? I usually use `\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading` in that place. Technically, what you do when you're coding the code for an environment is not to call `\@doendpe` but instead `\@endpetrue` and the code in `\end` does invoke the `\@doendpe`.

Comment: @Sigur I changed it to use `\@endpetrue`, I didn't test whether it'll work, as I didn't know where `tcolorbox` will use that code. Now I did actually test it, and it seems to work as well, so I opt for the "cleaner" approach of letting `\end` handle the rest.